# There is no option to add/edit dimension/size for Responsive Layout in IE 8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, ie-developer-tools

I'm testing a Responsive Web Design. I'm using Firefox, Chrome and IE for testing by using Web Developer Tool for each. I need some customized dimension/size for Tablet or Mobile. I have added some customized dimension/size on FF, Chrome for Responsive layout.

I have added/edited some customized dimension/size for desktop in IE 8. But I did not get any option to add or edit Responsive Layout (for Tablet or Mobile) dimension/size in IE 8. Can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: What is it worth on your project to have responsive design on IE8 for your project? I'd consider this answer to say, perhaps it's worth it to serve only the desktop design to IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158502/is-the-scope-of-responsive-design-worth-considering-for-ie8-as-of-2013